# MongoDB concurrent queries limit?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

Is there any limit of concurrent queries that mongodb can run in a second?

I am trying to implement an API that runs 300 queries in each request in mongodb.

So if there are 100 client requests in a second so the number of queries becomes 100 x 300 which is resulting in high latency.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The only limit is the number of conections mongo can have in parallel. Check out [net.maxIncomingConnections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.maxIncomingConnections)

> The maximum number of simultaneous connections that mongos or mongod will accept.  This setting has no effect if it is higher than
>   your operating system’s configured maximum connection tracking
>   threshold.

But still you'll need to monitor your system to figure out what's actually happening. 
And yes, **300** queries per API request is a bit too much even from networking perspective/requests parsing overhead.